# Probability for the length of the longest run in $n$ Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose a biased coin (probability of head being $p$) was flipped $n$ times. I would like to find the probability that the length of the longest run of heads, say $\ell_n$, exceeds a given number $m$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\ell_n > m)$.

It suffices to find the probability that length of any run of heads exceeds $m$. I was trying to approach the problem by fixing a run of $m+1$ heads, and counting the number of such configurations, but did not get anywhere.

It is easy to simulate it:

[image: Distribution of the length of the longest run of head in a sequence of 1000 Bernoulli trials with 60% change of getting a head]

I would appreciate any advice on how to analytically solve this problem, i.e. express an answer in terms of a sum or an integral.

Thank you.

Comment: You could have a Markov chain with states $0, 1, 2, \ldots l$ where the probability you move from $i$ to $i+1$ is $p$ and from $i$ to $0$ is $1-p$ for $i<l$ and the probability you move from $l$ to $l$ is $1$.  Then you could look at $n$th power of the transition matrix for this chain and read off the answer.

Comment: @Shawn What you suggest is a Markov chain that would give rise to geometric probability for the length of a single run, yet in $n$ simulations there might be more runs that that. The number of runs is random itself, so distribution I expect to get is not geometric. Besides your idea does not take into account the number of coin flipping.

Comment: I believe my "l" is your "m."  The number of flips you make is accounted for by the power of the transition matrix you look at.

Comment: It is well-known that $\ell_n / \log_2 n \to 1 \,\mathrm{a.s.}$, and not hard to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb{P}(\ell_n > (1-\epsilon)\log_2 n) \geq 1 - \exp( -n^\epsilon / 2 \log_2 n )$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: @Sasha: Both of your concerns are taken into account in Shawn's proposal. The fact that the transition from $m$ to $m$ has probability $1$ takes care of the possibility of multiple runs of length $m$; the system stays in state $m$ after the first such run. If all you need is the result for a particular $m$, you can use Shawn's approach. Another question is whether the structure of the transition matrix allows one to write the probability in closed form for general $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @Sasha: With respect to that last point (a closed form), I think you're out of luck; see [this simple case](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem+of+%7B%7B1-p%2C1-p%2C1-p%2C0%7D%2C%7Bp%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cp%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cp%2C1%7D%7D).

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for the answer. If you could copy your comments into an answer, I would accept that. Thanks for joriki for making me see how it works. In the hind site this is trivial, but I have not thought of this.

Comment: @Sasha: You're welcome. Obviously Byron and de Moivre proved me wrong on that last point :-)

Comment: @joriki Let's give de Moivre full credit. All I did was look it up! :)

Comment: @Byron: I did waver for a bit whether I should put you or de Moivre first there ;-)

Comment: This paper may be useful: [_The Longest Run of Heads_, M.K. Schilling](http://www.utktqyz.amc8.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020742.02p0021g.pdf)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This problem was solved using generating functions by de Moivre in 1738.
The formula you want is 
$$\mathbb{P}(\ell_n \geq m)=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor} (-1)^{j+1}\left(p+\left({n-jm+1\over j}\right)(1-p)\right){n-jm\choose j-1}p^{jm}(1-p)^{j-1}.$$

**References**

1. Section 14.1 *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Blom, Holst, and Sandell
2. Chapter V, Section 3 *Introduction to Mathematical Probability* by Uspensky
3. Section 22.6 *A History of Probability and Statistics and Their Applications before 1750* by Hald gives solutions by de Moivre (1738), Simpson (1740), Laplace (1812), and Todhunter (1865)

---

**Added:** 
The combinatorial class of all coin toss sequences without a run of $ m $ heads
in a row is 
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}(\mbox{seq}_{< m }(H)\,T)^k \,\mbox{seq}_{< m }(H), $$
with corresponding counting generating function 
$$H(h,t)={\sum_{0\leq j< m }h^j\over 1-(\sum_{0\leq j< m }h^j)t}={1-h^ m \over 1-h-(1-h^ m )t}.$$
We introduce probability by replacing $h$ with $ps$ and $t$ by $qs$,
 where $q=1-p$:
$$G(s)={1-p^ m  s^ m \over1-s+p^ m  s^{ m +1}q}.$$
The coefficient of $s^n$ in $G(s)$ is $\mathbb{P}(\ell_n<m).$

The function $1/(1-s(1-p^ m  s^ m q ))$  can be rewritten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k\geq 0}s^k(1-p^ m  s^ m q )^k 
&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{j\geq 0} {k\choose j} (-p^ m q)^js^{k+j m }\\
%&=&\sum_{j\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0} {k\choose j} (-p^ m q )^js^{k+j m }.
\end{eqnarray*}
The coefficient of $s^n$ in this function is $c(n)=\sum_{j\geq 0}{n-j m \choose j}(-p^ m q)^j$. Therefore the  coefficient of $s^n$ in $G(s)$ is $c(n)-p^ m  c(n- m ).$
Finally, 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\mathbb{P}(\ell_n\geq m)&=&1-\mathbb{P}(\ell_n<m)\\[8pt]
&=&p^ m  c(n- m )+1-c(n)\\[8pt]
&=&p^ m  \sum_{j\geq 0}(-1)^j{n-(j+1) m \choose j}(p^ m q)^j+\sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j+1}{n-j m \choose j}(p^ m q)^j\\[8pt]
&=&p^ m  \sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j-1}{n-j m \choose j-1}(p^m q)^{j-1}+\sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j+1}{n-j m \choose j}(p^mq )^j\\[8pt]
&=&\sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j+1}  \left[{n-j m \choose j-1}+{n-j m \choose j}q\right]p^{ jm } q^{j-1}\\[8pt]
&=&\sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j+1}  \left[{n-j m \choose j-1}p+{n-j m \choose j-1}q+{n-j m \choose j}q\right]p^{ jm } q^{j-1}\\[8pt]
&=&\sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j+1}  \left[{n-j m \choose j-1}p+{n-j m +1\choose j}q \right]p^{ jm} q^{j-1}\\[8pt]
&=&\sum_{j\geq 1}(-1)^{j+1}  \left[p+{n-j m +1\over  j}\, q\right] {n-j m \choose j-1}\,p^{ jm} q^{j-1}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Well damn, didn't see that coming.

Comment: @Byron Wow, thank you! This is really beyond my expectations. I will check those books out.

Comment: Great answer, Byron.

Comment: I found that Byron's answer doesn't give the right values. I don't have any of the books he mentions, so I figured it out from scratch. Big fun! I think the floor value for the upper limit of $j$ should be $\frac{n+1}{m+1}$. The term, ${{n-jm} \choose {j-1}}$ should multiply $p$ inside the big bracket. The term, $\frac{n-jm+1}{j}$ should be a term ${{n - jm + 1} \choose j}$. Can anybody tell me whether I got this right?

Comment: @DaveNeville Note that the first term in the sum is very dominant. Your term is equivalent for $j=1$, so the value of your formula will always be very close to the formula in the answer. BTW I ran a simulation and there was a discrepancy between my simulation on the one hand and your and Byron formula's on the other.

Comment: @DaveNeville I have added a derivation of the formula. Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 16):

Define a Markov chain with states $0, 1, \ldots m$ so that with probability $1$ the chain moves from $m$ to $m$ and for $i<m$ with probability $p$ the chain moves from $i$ to $i+1$ and with probability $1-p$ the chain moves from $i$ to $0$.  If you look at the $n$th power of the transition matrix for this chain you can read off the probability that in $n$ flips you have a sequence of at least $m$ consecutive heads.

Comment: Shawn Thanks for posting your question (+1). I think I should accept [Byron](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/940/byron-schmuland)'s answer as the one that provides an analytic answer. But your answer has proven a valuable lesson in Markov chains, so thank you again very much for that.

Comment: Yes, his answer is better.

Comment: @Shawn: The Markov should have $(m+1)(m+2)/2$ states instead of $m+1$. Each state should be an ordered pair $(R,r)$, where $0\le R\le m$ is the length (capped at $m$) of the longest run so far, and $0\le r\le R$ is the length of the current run. Then $(R,r)$ should go to $(R,0)$ with probability $1-p$, and go to state $(R+1,r+1)$ (or itself if $R=m$) with probability $p$.

Comment: @user1551 Shawn's proposal will do just fine, because as I said, the probability equals to probability that length of any run exceeds $m$. Indeed $\max(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k) > m$ is logically equivalent to $x_1>m \land x_2 > m \land \ldots \land x_k>m$.

Comment: There was an error in my comment above. State $(R,r)$ should go, with probability $p$, to $(R, r+1)$ if $r<R$, or $(R+1,r+1)$ if $r=R<m$, or itself if $r=R=m$.

Answer (score 8):

You can find a limiting distribution, otherwise it's a difficult problem and the closed form solution won't have much practical value.  See [this](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload%5flibrary/22/Polya/07468342.di020742.02p0021g.pdf) for an elementary approach.  **[Update]** Previous link moved to [this new address](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload%5flibrary/22/Polya/07468342.di020742.02p0021g.pdf).  "Longest Run of Heads", M.F.Schilling.

Comment: Thank you for the link. In regards to closed form comment, see Byron's answer above.

Comment: That's a nice reference. Thanks!

Comment: @karakfa Think the link got broken.

Comment: @KaiSikorski updated the link, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 8):

**Remark.**  The following  answer uses  the same  methodology  as the
accepted leading answer. It is self-contained, includes Maple code and
some asymptotics.  Perhaps it  can serve a  didactic purpose  and show
that the basic computation is very simple.

With  $z$ for successes  and $w$  for failures  we get  the generating
function

$$\left(1+z+\cdots+u\frac{z^m}{1-z}\right)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q}
\left(z+\cdots+u\frac{z^m}{1-z}\right)^q
\right)\frac{1}{1-w}.$$

Now as a  sanity check when we  put $w=z$ and $u=1$ we  should get all
binary strings. Doing the calculation we find

$$\frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-wz/(1-w)/(1-z)} \frac{1}{1-w}
\\ = \frac{1}{(1-w)(1-z)-wz} =
\frac{1}{1-w-z}.$$

Putting $z=w$ yields

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \frac{1}{1-z^2/(1-z)^2}
= \frac{1}{(1-z)^2-z^2} = \frac{1}{1-2z}$$

and the sanity check goes through.

Now for the probabilities we must subtract the value for $u=0$ from
the generating  function and  then set $u=1.$  We obtain for  the zero
term

$$\frac{1-z^m}{1-z} 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} 
\frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q} z^q \frac{(1-z^{m-1})^q}{(1-z)^q}\right)
\frac{1}{1-w}
\\ = \frac{1-z^m}{1-z} 
\frac{1}{1-wz(1-z^{m-1})/(1-w)/(1-z)}
\frac{1}{1-w}
= \frac{1-z^m}{(1-w)(1-z)-wz(1-z^{m-1})}
= \frac{1-z^m}{1-w-z+wz^{m}}.$$

To obtain the probabilities set $z=pv$ and $w=(1-p)v$ to get
for the one term

$$\frac{1}{1-w-z} = \frac{1}{1-(1-p)v-pv} = \frac{1}{1-v}$$

so that $$[v^n] \frac{1}{1-v} = 1.$$

The subtracted contribution from the zero term is

$$\frac{1- p^m v^m}{1-v+(1-p)p^m v^{m+1}}.$$

Now for coefficient extraction we write

$$[v^Q] \frac{1}{1-v+(1-p)p^m v^{m+1}}
\\ = [v^Q] \sum_{q\ge 0} (v-(1-p)p^m v^{m+1})^q
\\ = [v^Q] \sum_{q\ge 0} 
\sum_{r=0}^q {q\choose r} v^{q-r}
(-1)^r (1-p)^r p^{mr} v^{(m+1)r}.
\\ = [v^Q] \sum_{q\ge 0} 
\sum_{r=0}^q {q\choose r} v^{mr+q}
(-1)^r (1-p)^r p^{mr}
\\ = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor Q/m\rfloor} {Q-mr\choose r} 
(-1)^r (1-p)^r p^{mr}.$$

We thus get the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
1 - a_N + p^m a_{N-m}
\quad \text{where} \quad
a_Q = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor Q/m\rfloor} {Q-mr\choose r} 
(-1)^r (1-p)^r p^{mr}.}$$

Note that for $N\lt m$ we get

$$1- {N\choose 0} \times 1 \times 1\times 1 = 0$$

which is the correct result. Also for $N=m$ we obtain

$$1 - 1  - {0\choose 1} \times -1 \times (1-p) \times p^m
+ p^m \times 1 = p^m $$

which is correct as well.

Now  for  an asymptotic  we  note that  the  root  $\rho$ with  the
smalltest  modulus  of $1-v+(1-p)p^m  v^{m+1}$  is  the  one close  to
$v_0=1$ and we get from Newton-Raphson the first approximation

$$v_1 = v_0 - 
\frac{1-v_0 + (1-p)p^m v_0^{m+1}}{-1+(m+1)(1-p)p^m v_0^{m}}.$$

This works out to

$$1+ \frac{(1-p)p^m}{1-(m+1)(1-p)p^m}
= \frac{1-m(1-p)p^m}{1-(m+1)(1-p)p^m} = \rho.$$

The corresponding term from the partial fraction decomposition is

$$\frac{1}{v-\rho}
\mathrm{Res}_{v=\rho} \frac{1}{1-v+(1-p)p^m v^{m+1}}
\\ = \frac{1}{v-\rho} \times
\left.\frac{1}{-1+(m+1)(1-p)p^m v^{m}}\right|_{v=\rho}
\\ = - \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{1}{1-v/\rho}
\frac{1}{-1+(m+1)(1-p)p^m \rho^{m}}.$$

We thus obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
a_Q \sim \frac{1}{\rho^{Q+1}}
\frac{1}{1-(m+1)(1-p)p^m \rho^{m}}.}$$

We may replace $\rho$ by a better approximation from Newton-Raphson in
a setting where we require numerics,  which is done in the sample code
which now follows.

```
MRUNPROB :=
proc(N, m)
option remember;
local ind, d, pos, cur, run, runs, prob,
    zcnt, wcnt;

    prob := 0;

    for ind from 2^N to 2*2^N-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);

        cur := -1; pos := 1;
        run := []; runs := [];


        while pos <= N do
            if d[pos] <> cur then
                if nops(run) > 0 then
                    runs :=
                    [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];
                fi;

                cur := d[pos];
                run := [cur];
            else
                run := [op(run), cur];
            fi;

            pos := pos + 1;
        od;

        runs := [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];

        if nops(select(r -> (r[1] = 1 and r[2] >= m), runs)) > 0
        then
            wcnt := add(`if`(r[1] = 0, r[2], 0), r in runs);
            zcnt := add(`if`(r[1] = 1, r[2], 0), r in runs);

            prob := prob + p^zcnt * (1-p)^wcnt;
        fi;
    od;

    expand(prob);
end;

V1 :=
proc(N, m)
option remember;
local gf;

    gf := (1-p^m*v^m)/(1-v+(1-p)*p^m*v^(m+1));
    expand(1-coeftayl(gf, v=0, N));
end;

a := (Q, m) ->
add(binomial(Q-m*r,r)*(-1)^r*(1-p)^r*p^(m*r),
    r = 0 .. floor(Q/m));


V2 :=
proc(N, m)
option remember;
    expand(1-a(N,m)+p^m*a(N-m,m));
end;


a2 :=
proc(Q, m)
local rho;

    rho := (1-m*(1-p)*p^m)/(1-(m+1)*(1-p)*p^m);

    1/rho^(Q+1)*1/(1-(m+1)*(1-p)*p^m*rho^m);
end;

a3 :=
proc(Q, m, p)
local rho;

    rho :=
    sort([fsolve(1-v + (1-p)*p^m*v^(m+1), v)],
         (r1, r2) -> abs(r1-1) < abs(r2-1));
    rho := op(1, rho);


    1/rho^(Q+1)*1/(1-(m+1)*(1-p)*p^m*rho^m);
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you'll get a simple analytic formula. The problem is essentially equivalent to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48560/whats-the-chance-of-an-explicit-series-of-integers-in-a-limited-random-distribut/48584#48584), see my answer there: it involves the $n$-power of a $m \times m$ stochastic matrix (notice that there we are interested in the runs equal or greater than $m$), using a Markov chain (as suggested in the comments by Shawn). You can find also there some asymptotics.