# Probability that k or more i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables are realized 'success'

Tags: probability

Let $X_n\sim \operatorname{Bern}(p)$.

How does one calculate that there will be $k$ more more successes in a row? I can only think of taking the complement of the Geometric c.d.f.. 
$$1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^i(1-p)$$

But this can get tedious for a large $k$.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials/59749#59749 ?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: I think my proposition is simpler because I am not looking for the probability of the **longest** run exceeding a value but the probability that there will k or more **consecutive** successes. I'm not sure if they are different propositions, though.

Comment: Out of how many trials?

Comment: @Sasha: I run the experiment, if there is failure. I restart a chain and record the previous chain (with 0 successes), if there are two consecutive successes followed by one failure in the next chain, I stop again and start a new (third) chain. Now I evaluate an infinite number of these chains and count what fraction of these chains have k or more successes.

Comment: @Sasha : Since he used the word "geometric", I'm assuming that the number of trials is precisely the thing that is random.  You just keep going until you get the first failure.

Comment: @Wuschel The accepted answer does not solve (any plausible interpretation I can think of) the question you asked. This indicates you might want to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the probability of success on each trial is $p$, then the probability that the first $k$ trials are successes is $p^k$.  That's the probability that the length of the initial run of successes has length $k$ or more.

Comment: Or that any sequence of k consecutive trials result in a success.  Which is the probability that a particular sequence has k or more consecutive successes.