# Tossing a fair coin

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability for the length of the longest run in $n$ Bernoulli trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials)

Suppose a fair coin is tossed n times. Determine the probability that exactly r consecutive heads will occur. Is there a closed form to solve this problem?

Comment: This is the longest run problem. It does admit a closed form solution. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials) earlier question of mine.