# Is the probability of at least $k$ consecutive heads higher for a coin with higher probability of heads?

Tags: probability

Suppose a coin has probability $p$ for heads and $(1-p)$ for tail.
Let $P_{k,p}$ be the probability that
in $N$ flips there is a sequence of consecutive heads of length greater than
or equal to $k$. $N$ is some fixed number greater than $k$.

Does it follow that $P_{k,p}< P_{k,q}$ if 
$p$ < $q$?

I would greatly appreciate any hint/suggestion/solution!
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sasha I believe that is the formula, but I was wondering if I can somehow show that it is increasing or not... (with or without the formula) Thanks!

Comment: The expression for $P_{k,p}$ was given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple proof uses the beautiful idea of *coupling*. Roughly speaking, one *realizes* the results of the $p$ coins and of the $q$ coins on the same probability space, using the same randomness.

More precisely, consider $N$ i.i.d. random variables $U_k$, uniform on $(0,1)$, and decide that the result of flip $k$ is heads if and only if $U_k\leqslant p$. Then, replacing $p$ by $q\gt p$ increases the number of heads, pointwise, hence $P_{k,p}\leqslant P_{k,q}$.

Finally, the inequality is strict since, when $p\lt U_k\lt q$ for every $k$, the $q$ event is realized while the $p$ is not, and this has positive probability. (The argument shows that $P_{k,q}\geqslant P_{k,p}+(q-p)^N$.)

Comment: Nice answer! Just one question: is "alea" a misprint for "area", or is it Latin for "dice"?

Comment: Even after your edit, I'm still curious!

Comment: @Sasha, TonyK "Alea" seems to be a Gallicism for "randomness", thanks for spotting this.

Comment: So it's Latin for dice then. "Alea jacta est."

Comment: @Sasha Sure, "pointwise" refers to a comparison for each fixed $\omega$, hence for each realization of the family $(U_k)$.

Comment: @TonyK [Definitely](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/4020559/Locutions-latines-et-etrangeres-Larousse-pages-roses-Edition-1924-ocr).

Answer (score 0):

In the limit cases $p=0$ or $q=1$, the statement is true. $P_{k,p}$ seems continuous in $p$ and if it is continuous, the statement is true also for $p$ close to zero and $q\in(0,1)$.