# A fair die is rolled 1,000 times. What is the probability of rolling the same number 5 times in a row?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

A fair die is rolled 1,000 times. What is the probability of rolling the same number 5 times in a row? How do you solve this type of question for variable number of throws and number of repeats?

Comment: Hint: How many possible outcomes are there for the 1000 rolls? What is the probability of getting 5 in a row the same? Now you just need to compute all possible ways of getting 5 in a row for 1000 rolls and divide that by the number of possible outcomes.

Comment: You should wait before asking cross-sites https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492000/a-fair-die-is-rolled-1-000-times-what-is-the-probability-of-rolling-the-same-nu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to calculate the probability of rolling 6 at least 5 times in a row, out of 50 tries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893342/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-rolling-6-at-least-5-times-in-a-row-out-of)

This question is very similar to yours. You have to modify it for not having exactly the number 6 but the same number, so you will have different probabilities. Try calculating it for one specific number and then expand your approach.

Comment: You can not just calculate it for a specific number and then multiply it or something like that. Instead, you can use the fact that rolling any number $k$ times in a row in $n$ tries, is similar to rolling a specific number $k-1$ time in a row in $n-1$ tries. You can see it as tracking whether the dice rolls the same number as the one before (which has 1/6-th probabilty) and this $k-1$ times.