# Calculate the probability of $x$ successes in a row in n trials?

Tags: probability, summation

I am trying to find the probability that a person hits a baseball into a "success zone" five times in a row within $30$ total hits. The chance of hitting the success zone is $.3571$.

I am not sure whether to use cumulative binomial probability or any other summation sequence because of the "consecutive" part of the problem.

Basically I'm finding $x$ number of successes in a row in n trials though.

Comment: Exactly five times ? If yes, does he stops as soon as he gets 5 ?

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602123/what-are-the-odds-of-getting-heads-7-times-in-a-row-in-40-tries-of-flipping-a-co

Comment: Many similar answer in the link provided by Byron.

Comment: yes they stop after 5 @Canardini

Comment: @MeganCarver Wait my answer is not correct if they stop after 5.

Comment: @MeganCarver Could you explain your question slightly more? Do you want the probability that at some point, they get 5 consecutive successes in the 30 trials and the rest of the 25 trials can be anything?

Comment: Depending on the answer to that, perhaps see question `2076355` recently answered on this site.

Comment: oh well thank you anyways! @gowrath

Comment: @MeganCarver I can still try answer your question if you clarify it a bit as per my last comment.

Comment: refer to [the answer to this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082969/)