# What to do when a question and answer is too advanced

Tags: combinatorics

I was looking to get help with this problem?  I don't understand the solution.  Is that possible?
[What are the odds of getting heads 7 times in a row in 40 tries of flipping a coin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602123/what-are-the-odds-of-getting-heads-7-times-in-a-row-in-40-tries-of-flipping-a-co)

I am new, I understand the problem is random, or once one success is picked that success is put back in and the next success come from the same amount of tries.  I get really lost when it comes to factorials and recursion. I am so far off that I was looking in mathematical induction.  I found an interesting lesson in natural numbers and polynomials that could be helpful but I was wondering what other people thought of the problem and if they knew a better way from me to get to a solution that I understand.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Comment: It might be constructive to take this problem as a motivation to learn "factorials and recursion" *because* such topics come into play in solving the problem you want help with.  Sometimes a solution can be broken into "bite-sized" pieces, but it is a fact of life in mathematics that simply stated problems will often lead us into exploring new concepts and tools of analysis.

Comment: I found a precalculus class online at Coursera.  Taking a step back and exploring the challenges in this class have been more about sets, quadratics, coefficients, polynomials, and completing the square to this point.   'll be a while before I come across recursion and factorials.  Thanks for the reply! I hope to give an answer to the coin toss problem with great detail someday!