# Solve for martingale progression in CRAPS

Tags: probability, statistics

In craps the house has a 1.45% edge (51.45% chance to lose).  If you martingale+1 (double up + 1 unit, every time you lose) and do this for 15 outcomes, then double up the initial bet for 30 more outcomes you can almost 4x your money

The odds of 4 losses in a row would be .5145^4 = about 7%

But what are the odds I will make it 40 rolls(outcomes) without losing more then 4 in a row?

Comment: Here is a link to what might be the formula.  I’m just not smart enough to work it out :(  Please help :)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602123/what-are-the-odds-of-getting-heads-7-times-in-a-row-in-40-tries-of-flipping-a-co

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Can you also do this for 4 losses in a row?  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can treat this as a Markov chain.  We have $6$ states.  For $k=0,1,2,3,4$ state $k$ means that we currently have a string of $k$ losses.  State $5$ means that at some time, a string of $5$ losses has occurred, so state $5$ is absorbing.  If the probability of a loss is $p$ then the transition matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1-p&p&0&0&0&0\\
1-p&0&p&0&0&0\\
1-p&0&0&p&0&0\\
1-p&0&0&0&p&0\\
1-p&0&0&0&0&p\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$  and the initial distribution is $$X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
We simply have to compute $XP^{45}$ and read off the answers.

I wrote a python script to do this:

```
import numpy as np

p = (1+.0145)/2
P = np.zeros((6,6))
for i in range(5):
    P[i,0] = 1-p
    P[i,i+1] = p
P[5,5] = 1
X = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0])
Y = X@np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 45)
print(Y)
```

This produced the output

```
[0.2337404  0.12075448 0.06238393 0.03222866 0.0166499  0.53424264]
```

so the probability of $5$ losses in a row is $$.53424264$$

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it clicking the check mark, so that it no longer shows up as unsolved.  I don't quite understand your comment, but if you think that you have a positive expectation by following this strategy, you are mistaken.

Comment: The house edge is 1.45%, so the odds of losing would be 51.45%. Could you also do this for 4 losses in a row.  If you have your program still setup.  Thank you so much

Comment: I get $0.80915933$ for $4$ losses

Comment: That sounds right. Thank you

Comment: One more :) I’m trying to get it under .667 will I get there if I reduce the tries to 30 outcomes? Thank you for all your time and patience

Comment: Good guess!  With $30$ tries the probability of a run of $4$ losses is $ 0.65820036$

Comment: I think I would have asked this a different way.  Is my question the same as, what is the probability that I get less the 4 in row out of 30 tries?

Comment: The probability that a run of $4$ losses occurs sometime in a string of $30$ plays is about $0.65820036$.  The probability that no such run occurs is approximately $0.34179964$.