# Probability of Hitting 5 shots out of 20 shots in a row

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say there is a certain basketball player who has an accuracy of 50% for shooting his shots. Let's imagine he plays games where his average shots taken is 20.
What's the probability he hits AT LEAST 5 out of 20 of those shots in a row?

I know that hitting 5 shots in a row is simply 0.5^5, but the difference here is that the player is shooting out of a certain number of shots total. How would you solve this? Would it be relatively easy math?

I'm taking a Statistics class and a problem similar to this popped up. We are trying to do simulations of random numbers to estimate the percentage, but I wanted to find out the exact value. Any tips to get started? Please explain all reasoning :)
Thanks!

Comment: Must the successful shots be consecutive?  The "*in a row*" is ambiguous, at least to me, whether it is referring to the attempts or whether it is referring to the successful attempts.  If they don't matter to the order of occurrences, then look up information on the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: If the succesful shots must be consecutive, then check out [this similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929750/probability-of-a-75-freethrow-shooter-making-at-least-5-shots-in-a-row-out-of-1?rq=1) from two years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you mean at least one **streak** of $5$ or more  somewhere in the $20$ shots.

Let $P_n$ denote the probability of getting $5$ successive hits (streak) by the $n_{th}$ trial

then $P_{n} - P_{n-1}$ means that you get a streak for the first time   on the $n_{th}$ trial only,

which means that you had not got a streak on the $(n-6)_{th}$ trial, and also missed the shot after that, e.g. for first getting the streak on the $8_{th}$ trial, you didn't have a streak on the $2_{nd}$ , missed the shot on the $3_{rd}$ trial, and then got a streak of $5$.

Using the usual notation of $p$ and $q$ for probabilities of success/failure for *individual* trials,
$P_{n} - P_{n-1} = [1 - P_{n-6}]qp^5$ for $n\ge6$

Starting conditions are: $P_0\;\; thru\;\; P_4= 0, P_5 = (1/2)^5, P_6 = P_5+[1- P_0] *(1/2)^6, ...$

Proceed.....