# A good estimate on the probability of getting X "heads" in a row out of N coin flips?

Tags: probability

Let's say I flip a coin $N$ times. What is a good upper bound on the probability that I will, at some point during these $N$ flips, get $X$ "heads" in a row?

What is the probability that this will happen $K$ times?

(Example: If my flips are $HTHTHHHHTT$ then I got 3 heads in a row $K=2$ times)

The coin might be biased.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the probability of flipping a "head"? Is it $0.5$?

Comment: It can be a biased coin. I clarified, thanks.

Comment: I.e., a bound on the [exact answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/59749/16397) (with $m = X$).