# If a roulette wheel receives $100$ spins per evening, what is the chance that $5$ consecutive reds will occur sometime during the evening?'

Tags: probability, statistics, monte-carlo

In roulette, there are $38$ slots the ball can fall into. $18$ are red, $18$ are black, and $2$ are green.

If a roulette wheel receives $100$ spins per evening, what is the chance that $5$ consecutive reds will occur sometime during the evening?'

Attempted Solution:

I used the formula provided by Byron here: [Probability for the length of the longest run in $n$ Bernoulli trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials/59749#59749). I found that the probability is $.7295$. Intuitively, it sounds like this makes sense. However, I calculated this in excel, and excel stopped being able to compute the combinatorial portion of the formula due to extremely small values. For this reason I neglected those particular values.

In order to make sure I answered this correctly, I was hoping someone knew another way to solve this, whether it be a programming language you know or if you know how to run a Monte Carlo simulation in excel. Neither of which I know how to do.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to calculate it in Wolfram alpha? I tried [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+[%28-1%29^%28j%2B1%29%281%2F2%2B%28%28100-5j%2B1%29%2Fj%29%281-1%2F2%29%29[%28100-5j%29+choose+%28j-1%29]%281%2F2%29^%285j%29%281-1%2F2%29^%28j-1%29]+from+j%3D1+to+20) although you may want to check if formula is fully correct.

Comment: I tried a different Wolgram alpha URL but had difficulty inputting the formula. The formula looks right except I believe the probability is 18/38, not .5

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad. Result now [looks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251981/if-a-roulette-wheel-receives-100-spins-per-evening-what-is-the-chance-that-5?noredirect=1#2252023) much closer to yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(This implements ShawnD's answer to the question you link to).*

We can write down a recurrence for

- $a_n$: The probability that after $n$ spins we have *not* seen 5 consecutive reds, and the last spin was *not* red.
- $b_n$: The probability that after $n$ spins we have *not* seen 5 consecutive reds, and the sequence so far ends with *one* red.
- $c_n$: The probability that after $n$ spins we have *not* seen 5 consecutive reds, and the sequence so far ends with *two* reds.
- $d_n$: The probability that after $n$ spins we have *not* seen 5 consecutive reds, and the sequence so far ends with *three* reds.
- $e_n$: The probability that after $n$ spins we have *not* seen 5 consecutive reds, and the sequence so far ends with *four* reds.

Namely,
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1} \\ c_{n+1} \\ d_{n+1} \\ e_{n+1} \end{bmatrix} =
\frac{1}{38}\begin{bmatrix} 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 \\
18 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 18 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \\ c_n \\ d_n \\ e_n \end{bmatrix} $$
with the initial conditions $a_0 = 1$, $b_0=c_0=d_0=e_0=0$.

The probability we're looking for is to compute one minus the sum of the *first column* of
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 20/38 & 20/38 & 20/38 & 20/38 & 20/38 \\
18/38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 18/38 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 18/38 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 18/38 & 0 \end{bmatrix} ^{100}$$

With a linear-algebra library, raising a 5×5 matrix to the 100th power is quite quick and painless (using exponentiation by squaring it takes only 8 matrix multiplications). Or Wolfram Alpha [can do it for us](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B10.0%2F19,10%2F19,10%2F19,10%2F19,10%2F19%7D,%7B9%2F19,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,9%2F19,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,9%2F19,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,9%2F19,0%7D%7D%5E100), giving
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0.144322 & 0.14023 & 0.131708 & 0.113959 & 0.0769927 \\
0.0692934 & 0.0673289 & 0.0632374 & 0.0547155 & 0.0369667 \\
0.03327 & 0.0323268 & 0.0303623 & 0.0262707 & 0.0177489 \\
0.015974 & 0.0155211 & 0.0145779 & 0.0126134 & 0.00852181 \\
0.00766962 & 0.00745219 & 0.00699932 & 0.0060561 & 0.00409159 \end{bmatrix}$$
So we have
$$ 1-0.14432-0.06929-0.03327-0.01597-0.00767 = 0.72948 $$
which is consistent with your result.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware you could use linear algebra to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Henning Makholm's approach in Excel.  Make a column for each of $a$ through $e$ and a row for each number of spins.  As $a_{n+1}=\frac {20}{38}(a_n+b_n+c_n+d_n+e_n)$ and typical of the others $c_{n+1}=\frac {18}{38}b_n$.  The rows can be $n$ and you can write these equations in.  Copy down is your friend.

Comment: Indeed. In general doing matrix exponentiation by squaring should be more numerically robust than running the recurrence one step at a time, but I don't think that makes any significant difference in this case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  wouldn't it be even better to diagonalize the matrix and take the power of the diagonal?  At these parameters there is no numeric issue but you are right one could arise.

Comment: x @Ross: Possibly, at least if the exponent is large enough. I must admit I'm not up to speed on the possible numeric pitfalls of matrix diagonalization.