# Probability of at least $x$ successive wins in $n$ games

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I play $n$ games of chess against my friend. I have a probability $p$ of winning, my friend a probability of $1-p$ of winning a single game. Assume games are independent.

What is the probability that one of us wins $x$ successive frames in the $n$ games, where $ x \leq n$?

I thought about using the geometric distribution of some sorts as this seems natural, given we're on about successive trials, but I've not got anywhere with it.

Comment: Do you mean exactly $x$ successive games, or at least $x$ successive games?

Comment: @AdamRubinson at least

Comment: For a set $S$ with a finite number of elements, let $|S|$ denote the number of elements in $S$.  For $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,(n+1-x)\}$, let $A_k$ denote the set of outcomes that includes you winning $x$ consecutive games, starting from game $k$.  Let $B_k$ denote the set of outcomes that includes your friend winning $x$ consecutive games, starting from game $k$.  Then, you will need to calculate $|A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{(n+1-x)} \cup B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_{(n+1-x)}|$.  I suggest [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: "What is the probability that one of us wins..." : my previous comment made two assumptions: [1] You were focusing on (for example) your having at least one streak of consecutive wins, where the streak was $\geq x$. [2] You want the combined probability that either you or your friend has such a streak.

Comment: For large values of $n$, the math can get ugly here.  I suggest, that you practice with sample values like $n = 15$ and $x = 4$.  Also, if you can use a programming language, like Java, C, or Python, then with your sample problem, I suggest that you *sanity-check* your work via a computer program that counts all of the favorable sequences.  For example, your program won't have any problem checking $2^{(15)}$ various sequences of your wins combined with your losses, to see how many of these sequences satisfy the constraints.

Comment: By the way, per the problem's constraints, the probability that a specific chess game is drawn is $(0)$.

Comment: Yes but for example all the games could be "Armageddon" - whereby the game is either a win for White or Black (i.e. no draws). So this is not necessarily unrealistic.

Comment: I don't see how else to do this other than using a long Inclusion-Exclusion calculation as in user2661923's first comment. If $n=50, x= 13$ for example, then the calculation will be overwhelming, so at that point I would just run a few thousand simulations with a Python program and see what percentage of outcomes satisfy the condition.

Comment: This has been asked ton of times here.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials

Comment: @leonbloy Could you please reverse your decision? This is a distinct problem; the question you linked is for long runs of *heads only*. This question is for long runs of *heads or tails*.