# Expected length of the largest repeating substring given a distinct digit/character

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, computer-science, expected-value

A friend asked me this probability problem but I could not provide an accurate answer.

Suppose you are given a randomly generated N-ary string. Depending the string, certain digits/characters may form runs. For instance, in the string "29713007709**000**58444481622", for 0, the longest one of these runs is of length 3.

Given a *N* sized sample of digits/characters, a *L* length string, and a distinct character/digit (it does not matter which one — the probability of each one is equal) **what is the expected value for the length of the max run?**

Please give an explicit and exact formula if possible. If it is not possible, explain why.

As an example, for a randomly generated decimal string of length 10000 *(N=10, L=10000)*, the expected length of the max substring of zeros is ~3.6.

Comment: The expected number of runs is $\sum_{m=1}^L P(\ell_L \ge m)$, where the formula for $P(\ell_L\ge m)$ comes from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials), using $p=1/N$.

Comment: It can be shown that the length of the longest run tends to $\log_N L$. as $L\to \infty$. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885900039 for a citation, it's equation $(1)$ in the introduction.