# Probability of getting r tails in a row when tossing a coin n times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am having troubles understanding how to tackle the following question. The probability of getting tails when tossing a coin is $p=1/2$. I toss the coin n times, and want to determine the probability of getting r tails in a row ($r<n$).

Im thinking that there are $ ^nC_r$ ways that we can get r tails in a row when tossing the coin n times. The probability to not get a tail is also 1/2, so the probability of getting r tails in a row when tossing n times should be:
$P$=$ ^nC_r \cdot (1/2)^r \cdot (1/2)^{(n-r)}$ ?

Comment: Suppose you get the sequence $\color{red}{tt}h  \color{red}{tt}h \color{red}{ ttt}$. How many two tails in a row you count?

Comment: 3... but how would i describe it mathematically?

Comment: I don't hav a full solution yet. But you can start with $x=ttt$. Then a sequence  with a length of $n=8$  has the forms $xhxh, hxhx, xhhx,$ $hhhhhx, hhhhxh, .. $. This is how you can start.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials/59749#59749 for an exact answer to this question