# Expected number of strings of m or more consecutive successes

Tags: probability

Total number of trials = N. The trials are independent. Probability of success = p. Probability of failure = 1-p. What would be probability of getting m or more consecutive successes?

Is there some online/downloadable efficient software where I can input N, m, p and it gives me the answer? Can scientific calculators can do this job?

Comment: see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48584/354674) which gives you an immediate solution

Comment: @Igael: my numbers are big, are there any online tools, or scientific calculators that can do this for me?

Comment: @Igael: My N is more than 877 million and m is between 79000 and 80000

Comment: because 80000, expect almost 0 ! the billion doesn't change a lot. An algorithm may be optimized. For stackoverflow ? I'll try to compute tomorrow how many trillions of random checks are needed to expect to find this sequence 1 time with 50% of chances ( it's a reverse of a googol at 99.99% )

Comment: @Igael:The probability of success is very very high (6204/6205). which is .0.999838839645447.... Therefore, I do not expect it to be 0. Let me give you exact numbers then, N = 877646440, m = 79279, p(success) = 6204/6205. I want to know expected number of 79279 or more consecutive successes.

Comment: I bet 1 quarter of point on this result ! ( follow the first link to the answer for an estimation at the end of the post )

Comment: @Igael: as that question is slightly different (it may be same but described little different), if you can give me the formula here in terms of N, m, p, then I can calculate the approximation.

Comment: there is an upper bound of $N 2^{-m}$ and never $6204/6205$. Ask a question on stackoverflow and send me a comment to help you to write the matrix script